# Embedded flash (with XUL) doesnt work without debug flash player

Tags: flash, actionscript, xul

I've got a strange problem. I am making an actionscript movie for a XUL toolbar. My toolbar works great on my PC in mozilla. But when run on any other machine (with no debug flash player) it simply doesnt work and i have following exception:

Error: Error #2067: The ExternalInterface is not available in this container. ExternalInterface requires Internet Explorer ActiveX, Firefox, Mozilla 1.7.5 and greater, or other browsers that support NPRuntime.

I run it on Mozilla 3.6

Again, my flash works correctly on my PC and is not working on the other PC. Flash Player 10 on both, mine is debug version.

UPD: finally it seems ExternalInterface is working but movie is not even close to be fully functional. It stops its work in some constant code line. I do not have any trace() calls etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds a little like a security sandbox error.

are you running it locally or from the web?

(this is the first I've heard of XUL, guess I've been under a rock)

***edit**

in my experience flash player avoids allowing certain types of web access from the local machine if you run it from web server it should run fine.

also it may need to be wrapped in an html to support the javascript calls through ExternalInterface

if it's just you that needs to run it you might get it to work by lowering your flash security settings.

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502

also, may i ask what you are using ExternalInterface for?

Comment: The problems looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137223/flex-app-not-working-without-debug-version-of-flash-player except for i am not using any debug calls like trace etc, not even single try. I am developing a toolbar and i install it into my Mozilla as an .xpi module. It works on the PC where debug player is installed.

Comment: sounds as if you still need help finding the best way to work around this issue. i edited my answer to provide some more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

did you manage to launch it on any other pc?
 are you sure that .swf location is added to the [Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)?

Comment: I call allowDomain("*") at the beginning. For now i think problem is with sandbox. I create swf with XUL <html/embed> and thats why.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like sandbox problem. I export release build from Flash Builder 4. I do not know how to manage sandbox properties on build. I create swfplayer object with XUL  tag:

```
<toolbaritem id="swf-container-item" persist="width">
<html:embed hidden="true" wmode="transparent" id="sd-player" height="20px" width="200px" menu="false"
src="chrome://sdolsbar/content/out.swf" allowscriptaccess='always' align='center'
flashvars="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</toolbaritem>
```